# Drag Force per point in the body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag

Let us consider the common equation for drag force for any body.

$F_D = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2C_dA$

Here the A is the representative area which is the so called area of cross section of the body for most shapes under conditions of stable velocity (that is the angle of attack/velocity/viscosity of the medium is not so much).

Now my question is about the distribution of these forces.

1. **Given an extended body, how will the drag force be distributed across the points on the surface of the body**. That is given say a sphere, how is this force distributed throughtout the surface of the body? Say there are 60 points uniformly distibuted in the sphere. The entire sphere is moving forward with a velocity of $v$. So each point in the sphere has a velocity of $v$. In that case, will the drag force at each point be equal to $F_D$ ?
2. Next **if we consider an extended body where the velocities at each point is not the same, then will the same equation be applied to calculate the drag force at each point** ? Because my viewing of the drag force is kind of like a "whole body thing" and this contradicts with this notion.

I will post more clarification if required.

EDIT(1) : Posted more clarity on the questions.

Comment: $A$ does not have a 'value at each point'. It's an area.

Comment: Right. That is my concern. Also this is not a homework. I am a CS Grad student working on the simulation of a rigid body through a medium and I cam across this problem.

Comment: The homework tag does not just apply to actual homework assignments: it's a type of question.

Comment: This question seems to be "For a spherical body moving through a fluid how is the net drag force distributed across the surface?"

Comment: Edited the question for more clarity of what is asked.

Answer (score 1):

Each point on the surface will have a pressure (force normal to surface) and drag (force tangential to surface). By integrating over the entire surface you get the overall effect which is sometimes expressed in force/moments as

$$ F_D = \frac{1}{2} \rho v_{body}^2 A_{body} C_D 
\\ M_D = \frac{1}{2} \rho v_{body}^2 \ell A_{body} C_M $$

The $v_{body}$ used is just a convenient scaling factor to get things in the right units. The same with $A_{body}$. You will **not** use these equations to get the forces on a small area of a body. They work only for the entire body.

To get into the details of the forces in each infinitesimal surface area patch ${\rm d}A$ you will need  to solve the fluid dynamics equations for continuity and momentum which will give you the velocity vector and pressure at each location.